# Results differences between Keras ImageDataGenerator and custom DataGenerator using NPY files

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm currently learning NNs and trying to classificate RVL-CDIP public dataset. I'm using InceptionResNetV2 adapted to 16 classes.

I have good results using Keras *ImageDataGenerator* class for building my train and validation sets  ~80% ([Image Training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbxvr.png)).

Now I'm trying to train my model on .npy files : I exported ~30k images to (299,299) np arrays and built a custom *DataGenerator* using Sequences.
The training results are similar to the first training but the validation results are ~1% ([NPY Training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXK5H.png)).

It seems like i'm experiencing overfitting, although :

- I've been using the same data for both Image training and .npy training.
- I checked the image to .npy exportation, I did plot some arrays as images without problems

The main difference I spotted is the creation of training set and validation set. In the first training I use the *flow_from_directory()* method while in the second one I use a *pandas.DataFrame* containing path and class of each element in the dataset.

Below is my code for creation of the Generators :

```
def get_custom_data_generator(df_dataset, batch_size, df_train=pd.DataFrame(), df_validation=pd.DataFrame()):

    global STEPS_PER_EPOCH_TRAIN
    global STEPS_PER_EPOCH_VALIDATION

    if len(df_dataset) > 0:
        config.class_names = df_dataset['CLASS'].unique()
        num_classes = len(config.class_names)
        
        # Shuffling the dataset :
        df_dataset = df_dataset.sample(frac=1)       
        
        split_row = int(df_dataset.shape[0] * config.dataset_creation.split.train)
        df_splits = np.split(df_dataset, [split_row], axis=0)
        df_train = df_splits[0]
        df_validation = df_splits[1]

    STEPS_PER_EPOCH_TRAIN = df_train.shape[0] // batch_size
    STEPS_PER_EPOCH_VALIDATION = df_validation.shape[0] // batch_size
    if len(df_train) > 0 and len(df_validation) > 0:
        train_set_generator = DataGenerator(df_train,
                                        x_col = ['PATH'],
                                        y_col = ['CLASS'],
                                        batch_size = batch_size,
                                        num_classes = num_classes)
        validation_set_generator = DataGenerator(df_validation,
                                        x_col = ['PATH'],
                                        y_col = ['CLASS'],
                                        batch_size = batch_size,
                                        num_classes = num_classes)

        return train_set_generator, validation_set_generator
    return None, None
```

And here is my DataGenerator class:

```
class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, df, x_col, y_col=None, batch_size=32, num_classes=None, shuffle=True, width=299, height = 299):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.df = df
        self.indices = self.df.index.tolist()
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.x_col = x_col
        self.y_col = y_col
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.dim = (width,height)
        self.n_channels = 1
        self.map_classes = map_classes(df['CLASS'].unique())

        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.indices) // (self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        index = self.index[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch = [self.indices[k] for k in index]
        X, y = self.__data_generation_npy(batch)
        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.index = np.arange(len(self.indices))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.index)

    def __data_generation_npy(self, batch):
        '''
        Create a batch by using the CurrentNPY directory instead of the Current directory
        '''
        npydataset_path = "D:/dataset/RVL/NPY"
        df = self.df
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, 3))
        y = np.empty(self.batch_size, dtype=int)
        for i, id in enumerate(batch):
            doc_row = df.loc[id]
            path = str(doc_row['PATH'])
            path = os.path.join(npydataset_path, path)
            typologie = str(doc_row['CLASS'])
            path += ".npy"
            with open(path, 'rb') as f:
                npyfile = np.load(path, allow_pickle=True)
            try:
                npyfile = np.expand_dims(npyfile, axis=3)
                X[i,]=npyfile[0]
            except ValueError:
                print('Value Error : npyfile=', npyfile.shape)
            y[i] = self.map_classes[typologie]
        X = np.array(X)
        obj_to_file(X)
        Y = np.array(y)
        Y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(Y, num_classes = self.num_classes)
        return X, Y
```

I will be thankful if someone could help me figure out what I did wring with my DataGenerator, or what could I test in order to spot the problem.

Comment: What's `map_classes` in your `DataGenerator` constructor? One guess is that you create a different mapping of classes in your train set and your validation set, leading to bad validation score.

Comment: `map_classes` was the problem ! It creates a dict of class_names and after checking what it returns, it created two different dict so validation score was bad at the end. I'll upload an answer as soon as I have results from a new training